# Como salvar o estado de uma TreeView em ASP.NET / C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma treeview que está persistida em Banco de Dados e, a partir da aplicação, é possível adicionar ou remover itens, tanto da TV quanto do BD. Grande problema é que não encontro uma maneira simples de salvar o estado de "utilização" do usuário (ExpandedNodes) para melhorar a usabilidade da aplicação.

Em todos os fóruns e soluções que pesquisei colocam como necessário salvar os nodes em Session ou Cookie e depois realizar a adição dos nodes recursivamente. Até aí tudo bem, cumpre com o primeiro objetivo: Salvar o estado de utilização da TV. Porém, barra na possibilidade de adicionar e remover itens dinamicamente, lembrando que os dados vêm do BD.

Alguém conhece algum método para lidar com essa questão?

Seguem abaixo os códigos que estou utilizando para salvar e restaurar a TV:

```
public void SaveTreeView(TreeView treeView, string key, HttpContext context)
{
    context.Session[key] = treeView.Nodes;
}

public void RestoreTreeView(TreeView treeView, string key, HttpContext context)
{
    if (new TreeViewState(key).IsSaved)
    {
        treeView.Nodes.Clear();

        TreeNodeCollection nodes = (TreeNodeCollection)context.Session[key];
        for (int index = nodes.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            treeView.Nodes.AddAt(0, nodes[index]);
        }
        this.SaveTreeView(treeView, key, context);
    }
}
```

Abaixo segue o algoritmo que estava tentando escrever para lidar com o problema de inserções e deleções e a chamada dele no page_load():

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        state.RestoreTreeViewAfterUpdate(tvwCadastro, "TreeViewState", HttpContext.Current);
    }
}

public void RestoreTreeViewAfterUpdate(TreeView treeView, string key, HttpContext context)
{
    RestoreTreeView(treeView, key, context);

    SystemUnderTestDB sutDB = new SystemUnderTestDB();
    TesteDB tesDB = new TesteDB();

    foreach (DataRow drTeste in tesDB.SelecionarTesteSUT(Convert.ToInt32(context.Session["SUT"])).Tables[0].DefaultView)
    {
        TreeNode c = new TreeNode() { Text = drTeste["tes_titulo"].ToString(), Value = "2" + drTeste["tes_codigo"].ToString() };

        foreach (TreeNode nodeSUT in treeView.Nodes)
        {
            if (!treeView.Nodes.Contains(c))
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode() { Text = drTeste["tes_titulo"].ToString(), Value = "2" + drTeste["tes_codigo"].ToString() };
                treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pelo que percebo seu problema é puramente de algoritmo (forma como está salvando e obtendo estes valores), realmente a melhor alternativa pra esses casos é o uso de Session, gerenciando isso sempre que adicionar ou remover um nodo.

Comment: Exatamente, certamente é um problema de algoritmo, mas ainda não consegui identificar algo prático para fazer a verificação das tuplas em relação aos nós da TreeView. Vou editar o texto e incluir o algoritmo que estava tentando escrever para lidar com este problema.